# mvc3 dropdownlist only enters controller for first change of each item

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following dropdownlist defined -

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.myEntity, new { @id = "ddList" })
```

with the following jquery -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {        
        $("#ddList").change(function () {            
            var myid = $("#ddList").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Controller/Action/',
                data: {
                    'id': myid
                },
                datatype: 'html',
                success: function (result) { success(result); }
            });
        });

    });


    function success(result) {        
        $("#partial").html(result);
    }
</script>
```

every time that I change the selection in the drop down, it enters the controller correctly the first time.
If I then select the same option a second time, my controller action is never entered.

Does anyone have any idea why my code doesn't hit the controller for any subsequent drop down selection.

Thanks

EDIT -

Here is the contents of the div partial - it actually renders an mvc partial view -

```
<div id="partial" style="height:  90%">
        @Html.Partial("_Activities")    
</div>
```

Comment: Are you replacing the dropdown with the ajax result ?

Comment: That is my question to you. What is the content of div partial ?

Comment: Your code above works for me... just to be sure I understand - you're actually changing the value of the dropdown each time, not wanting to select the same value again correct?

Comment: when I change the selection, it works fine.  It changes the partial view to the expected information.  If I then select something else, that renders fine as well.  If I then select the first option again, it changes the partial view, but it doesn't go back into the controller to update the data, it just rerenders the original partial view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a caching issue to me. Caching is true by default in JQuery Ajax for data type HTML, set it to false. try this:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: 'Controller/Action/',
                data: {
                    'id': myid
                },
                datatype: 'html',
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) { success(result); }
            });
```